# SSL certificate in Advanced REST Client for Chrome

Tags: rest, ssl

Recently, 2-SSL verification was added to the server I'm working with.

Up until now I've used [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for server's REST API (mostly GET calls).
Since the SSL change, I'm getting `0 NO REPONSE ERROR`:

[image: screenshot]

How can I add SSL certificates to my GET calls? (I do have the .cnf & cacert + cakey files)

Answer (score 7):

From [the bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-rest-client/issues/detail?id=69), you can go to the page in your web browser and select 'Proceed Anyway'.  After doing that my REST calls went through fine.

Comment: This is not a solution - I've been struggling with a RESTful service and pivotal (who won't drop SSL3 for some reason).  Chrome doesn't support it anymore, each session I need to open the URL the application is following by going into the console.  Not something a non tech savvy person would even begin to know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Advanced REST Client extension in recent upgrades has resolved this issue , with additional add on **ARC Cookie exchange**

Link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-cookie-exchange/apcedakaoficjlofohhcmkkljehnmebp